# jquery inserting text to textarea after X characters

Tags: jquery

```
    var currentposition = 10; // after 10 characters
    var text = ":)";

    $(".insert").click(function () {
           // Need help here
    });

<textarea id="messagebox">Example text for the code</textarea>
```

How can I insert text in a textarea after a certain amount of characters (there is text in the textarea), in this case 10. There also may not be any text in the textarea at all, in which case currentposition will be 0.

The purpose of this code is to enter smileys at the current cursor position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using something like `.substring()`:

```
var currentposition = 10;
var text = ":)";

$('textarea').val($('textarea').val().substring(0,currentposition) + text + 
    $('textarea').val().substring (currentposition));
```

**[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/bNyy7/)**

UPDATE: If you want to have the cursor positioned at the end of the text, you can try calling the `.focus()` method **before** changing the textarea's value:

```
$('textarea').focus().val($('textarea').val().substring(0,position) + ' :) ' + 
    $('textarea').val().substring (position));
```

But I'm not sure it'll work in all browsers (there may be issues with IE)

Comment: Not part of the question, but maybe you know how to move the cursor after the inserted text, not before it. Currently when I insert two smileys in a row the second one goes before the first one.